# URL rewriting causing internal server error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url

I'm a newbie to URL re-writing.

I have an anchor text in home page, when clicked shall open another page. The target url displayed in browser when the link is clicked is
http://example.com/index.php?p=one/two/three/pdp&abc=436

instead i want to display in the URL
http://example.com/index.php?p=shopping/shop/ipad/pdp&abc=436.

So essentially what i'm looking at is substitution in the URL from
one/two/three

to 
shopping/shop/ipad

I want the URL http://example.com/index.php?p=one/two/three/pdp&abc=436
 to look like http://example.com/index.php?p=shopping/shop/ipad/pdp&abc=436.

Note that i have 14,000 pages, so cannot physically go & change everywhere.
i want this to happen using url rewriting. So in the root i have added to .htaccess the following lines.

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule  ^shopping/shop/ipad/?$ one/two/three/pdp [NC,L]
```

but this is giving internal server error.

How can i acheive displaying a better url ?
thanks

Comment: `RewriteRule` doesn't work on query stings directly. You'll need to look at `RewriteCond`.

Comment: Take a look at the apache error logs. Make sure mod_rewrite is enabled . (`a2enmod rewrite`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  p=one/two/three/(.*)
RewriteRule .*  http://example.com/index.php?p=shopping/shop/ipad/%1? [R=301,L]
```

It will redirect:

`http://example.com/index.php?p=one/two/three/pdp&abc=436`

To:

`http://example.com/index.php?p=shopping/shop/ipad/pdp&abc=436`

I am assuming `` `p=one/two/three/ `` and `p=shopping/shop/ipad/` are constants. If they are variables you should update the question and describe their relationship and patterns, to be able to capture and substitute them.

**SECOND OPTION:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  p=one/two/three/([^/]+)&([^/]+)=([^/]+).*
RewriteRule .*  http://example.com/index.php?p=shopping/shop/ipad/%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]
```

It will redirect:

`http://example.com/index.php?p=one/two/three/anything1&anything2=anything3`

To:

`http://example.com/index.php?p=shopping/shop/ipad/anything1/anything2/anything3`

Comment: Thanks Felipe. This one worked. I'm looking at a slight variation. Suppose that i want http://example.com/index.php?p=shopping/shop/ipad/pdp/abc/436 instead of http://example.com/index.php?p=shopping/shop/ipad/pdp&abc=436 how can i do that ? many thanks#

Comment: I'll update my answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Redirect 301 old_url new_url
```

Example:

```
Redirect 301 index.php?p=one/two/three/pdp&abc=436 http://example.com/index.php?p=shopping/shop/ipad/pdp&abc=436
```

I hope you solve your problem, sorry if you do not, I have not tried.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteRule` will only work on the **path** part of the URL (the `/index.php` part), not the **query string** (everything after the `?`). You need a `RewriteCond` to capture the query string, and then a `RewriteRule` which leaves the path part alone, but changes the query string.

Try the following (which I can't verify at the moment, sorry):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}   p=one/two/three/pdp/&(.*)
RewriteRule *                 /index.php?p=shopping/shop/ipad/&%1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

The first rule basically says "*if* the query string matches *this pattern* (remembering extra stuff)", and the second rule says "*then* change *anything* to `/index.php?p=shopping…` and add the stuff you remembered from the Cond". The `%1` is a *back reference* to the capture buffer of the last *Cond* match, as opposed to `$1`, which is for back references into the *Rule* pattern.

It's ok for the second rule to match everything, since it will only fire if the first rule matches. The `R=301` says to perform an actual redirect with code 301 (for example), since otherwise visitors will never see the change.

Two things about this method:

1. The link in your page will not be changed, it will still show up as `…one/two/three…` on mouseovers and similar. The change will be applied only when someone actually visits it.
2. This actual example is quite fragile; it depends on the `p=` part of the query string coming first, and something actually following it. You'll need to change the regular expression if you have more cases.

For more information, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

Yet another method:

If you have enough access to change the `index.php` script, you could do the rewrite *there*, and not in the web server. This has the advantage that you have a powerful language at your disposal, which already has good handling of query strings.